# Rolling n fair dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

You have n fair dice and score a point if all n dice come-up as 6.

a) Probability of scoring a point in one round

> My ans: $1/6^n$

b) In $2*6^{n-1}$ rounds, how many points you expect to score

> Is this equal to np = $2*6^{n-1}$*$(1/6^n)$ ?

c) Suppose n is very large. Find the approximate probability that you score at least 2 points in $2 × 6^{n-1}$ rounds. (Your answer should not involve n or any summations)

> If n is large, then will this become poisson distribution? I don't know how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to the first two questions are correct.

For the third one, as you pointed out we should use the Poisson approximation. It should be clear that the number of points you score in $2 \times 6^{n-1}$ rounds has a binomial distribution with parameters $2 \times 6^{n-1}$ and $6^{-n}$. Now the goal is to prove convergence in distribution to a Poisson with parameter $1/3$.

To see this, let $X_N$ be a binomial $(N,\frac{1}{3N})$. Then $X_N \Rightarrow \text{Poisson}(1/3)$ by the Poisson limit theorem. Thus if we extract ($N = 2\times 6^{n-1}$), we have $$Binomial(2\times 6^{n-1}, 6^{-n}) \Rightarrow Poisson(1/3)$$
In particular, if we denote by $Y$ a Poisson random variable with parameter $1/3$, then the probability you are looking for is simply 
$$P(Y \geq 2) = 1 - P(Y=0) - P(Y=1) = 1-\big(1+\frac{1}{3}\big)\exp\big(-\frac{1}{3}\big)$$